# Capacitor in LC filter

Tags: filter

Please excuse me for this noob question. I have been wrapping my head around this for some time. If it's irrelevant here please comment, I'll delete this question.
If a capacitor blocks DC and passes only AC, why is it used along with an inductor in an LC filter?

Comment: Capacitors have low impedance at high frequency.  Inductors have low impedance at low frequency.  Impeding low or high frequencies is a very useful feature in a filter that is designed to pick out some range of frequencies.  Beyond that, you would pick some set of components because it gives you the frequency response you want.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking "noob questions" over here, but frankly, I'm a bit confused by your question. All I can say at this point is that they are both completely valid uses of capacitors in electrical circuits. If you want more information than that, you'll have to tell us more, preferably with regards to your understanding of capacitors and LC filters.

Comment: The purpose of LC filter is to provide filtered DC output. Inductor provides reactance and allows only DC to pass through but capacitor blocks DC and allows AC. This is the part I don't seem to understand.

Comment: The L is in series and the C in parallel with the load. The capacitor resists the change of voltage and the inductor resists the change of current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking about an LC lowpass filter (which is just one kind of LC filter), not the general case of an LC filter (which could be high pass, band pass, etc).  My guess is you are looking at picture of some other kind of LC filter rather than a low pass.  If you look at the low pass topology, it is pretty obvious what the capacitor is doing:

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lowpass_Filter_LC.svg]

Since as you point out the capacitor blocks DC but passes AC, the AC part of the signal is shorted to ground while the DC part is passed to the output.  You may also find this link useful, which compares the various types of low pass filters that can be implemented with passive components:

https://electronicbase.net/low-pass-filter-calculator/